storing data in a server and linking the website to it
I have a digital ocean droplet and have an SSH client to it, I have installed apache2 into it, as I didn't have much idea related to servers. I need to store the data realtime in that cloud server and link my website to it. My server storage is 24 GB.
How do you think I should proceed with that?
I tried using apache2 but it was showing the default page of Ubuntu on it, and no changes were there.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
